# Why doesn't a BackgroundWorker need Invoke in the ProgressChanged event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

Since the `ProgressChanged` event handler is raised from somewhere within the `DoWork` event handlers, shouldn't they be called on the asynchronous operation thread, which `DoWork` also runs on, instead of the UI thread, and therefore require Invoke or `BeginInvoke` to manipulate controls?

My guess is that some magic is happening within the `ReportProgress` method, but how does it even know, which one is the correct thread to invoke the `ProgressChanged` event handlers on?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext Or you can use ilspy to  look under the covers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `RunWorkerAsync`, the `BackgroundWorker` internally creates a new [`AsyncOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperation) associated with the current synchronization context, as retrieved through the [`AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperationmanager.synchronizationcontext.aspx) static property.

This synchronization context would be an instance of a class deriving from [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext). The specific type depends on the synchronization model provider your application uses. If you’re running Windows Forms, it would be [`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext); on WPF; it would be [`DispatcherSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext).

When you subsequently call `ReportProgress` on the background thread, the `BackgroundWorker` would internally call [`Post`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post) on the aforementioned `SynchronizationContext` instance, thereby dispatching the operation to the associated thread asynchronously.

In Windows Forms, this is implemented as a [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) call; on WPF, it becomes a [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke) call.

Comment: I just read a bit about `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`, as mentioned in rene's comment. Just so I get that right: `AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext` yields "the" `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`, which happens to have `AutoInstall` set to `true` by default, hence knowing.. What exactly? The thread on which the message queue is running, or the thread on which the first control is created? Or does it just save the "Main Form" to later call `BeginInvoke` on that? As a side note, I noticed when the manipulated control had been created on another thread, it doesn't work.

Comment: The `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` stores an internal reference to the `Control` (typically a `Form`) on which to call `BeginInvoke`.