# WebRequest hangs user interface

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I'm doing simple request with WebRequest and the app just hangs until the response comes back. How do I fix this?

I have read a lot of topics and they all say to use threads. I don't know how to use them; can anyone provide an example of the following that doesn't hang the user interface?

```
private string SimpleRequest(String url)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    stream.Dispose();
    reader.Dispose();
    return result;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String googleHtml = simpleRequest("https://facebook.com");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `BackgroundWorker` in order to use another thread than UI thread. [Here is a sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20627/BackgroundWorker-Threads-and-Supporting-Cancel).

You can also cancel or display progress:

```
public partial class fmMain : Form
{
    private void btnrunBackgroundWorker_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // Create a background worker
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler( bw_DoWork );

        // run in another thread
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();     
    }

    private void bw_DoWork( object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e )
    {
        String facebookHtml = simpleRequest("https://facebook.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: btw quick question, if i would like to use it on for loop, i just add on the loop Thread.Sleep( 100 );?

Comment: if you want to make many queries (many call of simpleRequest) without waiting completion you can make async call of your simpleRequest but if you want to make many call waiting completion you can use callback to get completion and in this one to start another SimpleRequest call (waiting with Thread.Sleep on a specific time is good way ;-)

Answer (score 8):

If you are using c# 5.0 it is too easy

```
public async void Test1()
{
      WebClient wc = new WebClient();
      richTextBox1.Text =  await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://facebook.com");
}
```

You can convert your method to `awaitable` also

```
private Task<string> simpleRequest(String url)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            stream.Dispose();
            reader.Dispose();
            return result;
        });
}
```

and call as

```
public async void Test2()
{
      richTextBox1.Text =  await simpleRequest("https://facebook.com");
}
```

For lower versions of C#, See other answers.

Comment: tanks,its best answer

Answer (score 3):

You're doing network access on the main UI thread.  The UI has a main thread which loops and updates the UI.  If you do network access on that thread, the UI will not update and it will appear hung until your method returns and the loop can continue.

Consider doing your work on a background thread.  One easy way to do that in .net is the BackgroundWorker class.

The official documentation has a nice example of it's usage:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a
>   separate, dedicated thread. Time-consuming operations like downloads
>   and database transactions can cause your user interface (UI) to seem
>   as though it has stopped responding while they are running. When you
>   want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated
>   with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a convenient
>   solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [**BackgroundWorker**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) so your *main UI thread does not hang!*

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync("https://facebook.com"); // start async operation
}
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = simpleRequest(e.Argument.ToString()); // set result in async operation
}
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        // show result here
        // or access/manage result here
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        // manage/show error
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    }
}
private String simpleRequest(String url)
{
     // your code goes here
}
```

You could implement **backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged** too, so that the user can see progress of loading webSite. (sideNote: see this question for details on [ProgressChanged and Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121708/why-doesnt-a-backgroundworker-need-invoke-in-the-progresschanged-event-handler/12121804#12121804))

Comment: you will get the result string with e.Result.ToString() as shown in my example :D You may decide on yourself what to do with it, see comments in RunWorkerCompletet

Comment: i did that i tried to output it, but nothing there, it doesn't trigger backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted...

Comment: perhaps you got an error, try to show any error message - I'll  update my answer

Comment: :(( why its not working for me, here is the full code please check http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=2EZeUK4S

Comment: update your code to show any error messages as shown  in my updated answer - perhaps your firewall is blocking or anything else - MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);

Comment: nope nothing :(, btw i should add this to the clickbutton right BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();?

also if you don't mind please save the project and upload it